# Correct DNS settings but not working in the browser

Tags: dns

My domain isn't resolving and I have pinged the IP address but it shows there is 0% packet loss. But when I go to the site in a browser, it can't connect to it.

I've tried for few hours to figure this out, and there is so much information out there but I feel like I've tried it all. I have checked my DNS settings, and I have checked my server logs for errors etc. What could be wrong?

I hope this isn't too much of a noob question, but I am kinda new to DNS stuff. I've done it before but find it hard to figure out the cause if something does go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to troubleshoot DNS issues, here is a list of common troubleshooting steps:

- Double-check your DNS settings:

  This means checking that your A record(s) is/are correct, and that they point to a valid (and the correct) IP address; checking that your CNAME record(s) is/are correct. Also check other records, if applicable;
- Try visiting your website by entering its IP address into the Address Bar of your browser. If you still cannot connect to the site in a browser, it is likely that you are entering the IP address incorrectly, or that your provider is experiencing server or DNS problems, or that your DNS Server is not configured correctly (if you are running your own DNS Server). In this case, I would contact your provider, or go back to the documentation for the DNS Server you are using;
- Flush your DNS cache. You can do this by entering the following command at a Command Prompt: `ipconfig /flushdns`, and then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
- Ensure that your Hosts file contains valid entries. You can find out more about the Hosts file at the following address, which also contains a link to download a Hosts file with default configuration:

  [How can I reset the Hosts file back to the default?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/972034)

Comment: well what happens when i flush the dns do i need to restart my compputer or disconnect from the internet before i try to visit the website again?

Comment: Simply put, flushing the DNS Cache forces your PC to clear the DNS Cache which, in turn, causes it to lose entries that it has previously discovered. When this happens, your computer has no other choice but to retrieve new and updated information as you begin to visit websites again. And yes, you should restart your computer after you have flushed the cache.

This is why flushing the DNS cache sometimes helps resolve issues; entries can become invalid, either due to them being changed or due to the entries needing to be updated.

Comment: @hello123 Are you running your own DNS Server?

Comment: Thank u. I figured it out it was the cache. Now i remember i was playing around with some dns utility some weeks ago and it mentioned something about a cache. Flushing it fixed it fo r me thanks

Comment: and no im not using a custom dns server